# Best practices for making a 2D array/collection class

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, 2d

I am working on a general library which is going to be widely used in other applications. You can say that it is a kind of SDK library.

I need to implement a 2D collection implementation. It is going to be a generic template abstract class. So what are good practices for making a 2D array or collection. It is like a grid structure.

Here is what I have done for a 1D collection.

```
public abstract class BaseCollection<T> : Collection<T>
```

What should I do for 2D collection. [,] or something else.

Comment: If it's a 2D collection then I don't think you should derive from a 1D base class (because you'll get non-sense methods like Add). Implement your own collection and THEN add interface implementations that make sense (for example IEnumerable<T> if sequential scanning has sense). It doesn't mean that you can't use them under the hood but your users should see that (which element you will remove if THEY call RemoveAt(123)?)

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of options, but it will depend in part on what the actual implementation of your 2D collection is.

If you just want a 2D array then there is a special syntax for that.  This is a 2D string array:

```
string[,] twoDimStringArray = new string[4,5];
```

Another option is to have a list of lists:

```
List<List<string>> listOfListOfString = new List<List<string>>();
```

You could have a jagged array:

```
string[][] arrayOfArraysOfString = new string[5][];
```

Generally speaking I would discourage you from having a class that extends another collection type.  It's generally best to *encapsulate* another type of collection.  If your class is itself exposed as a collection then use the various interfaces that are appropriate, such as `IEnumerable`, `ICollection`, `IList`, `ISet`, etc.

If you have a two dimensional indexed list-style collection then you could perhaps have your class be an `IList<IList<T>>`, or an `ICollection>, if you want to expose the level of functionality that those interfaces would (you might not, it's hard to tell without knowing more of the context).

Comment: I am thinking to implement [,]. This suits with my condition.

Comment: In 1D implementation I had some function which were being used widely, like move up, move down, delete, can move up, and since I am also writing unit tests so code was repetitive, so I decided to write a base collection class and its unit tests so that derived class don't need to write same unit-tests again and again,

Comment: @FaisalHafeez The implementation of classes like that *shouldn't* be repetitive.  If they are it means that you don't really have different types of collections, you should just have one and leverage composition instead.  Have classes with a collection as a field, rather than by inheriting from a collection type.  If the collections really are different the implementation of those kinds of methods, and even the public API that they'll be able to expose, should be different.  Look at classes like `Dictionary`, `List`, `LinkedList`, `HashSet`, etc.  They don't have any common base collection.